# basic react native app not showing any text only white screen with app name on simulator

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

i am trying to run simple react native app. just text 'Hello World!', it's supposed to be my first app in react native. below is my simple app.js file

```
    /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow
 */

import React from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  Header,
  LearnMoreLinks,
  Colors,
  DebugInstructions,
  ReloadInstructions,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <StatusBar barStyle="dark-content" />
      <SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Header />
          {global.HermesInternal == null ? null : (
            <View style={styles.engine}>
              <Text style={styles.footer}>Engine: Hermes</Text>
            </View>
          )}
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Step One</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Edit <Text style={styles.highlight}>App.js</Text> to change this
                screen and then come back to see your edits.
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>See Your Changes</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <ReloadInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Debug</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                <DebugInstructions />
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Learn More</Text>
              <Text style={styles.sectionDescription}>
                Read the docs to discover what to do next:
              </Text>
            </View>
            <LearnMoreLinks />
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.lighter,
  },
  engine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 0,
  },
  body: {
    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  },
  sectionContainer: {
    marginTop: 32,
    paddingHorizontal: 24,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: '600',
    color: Colors.black,
  },
  sectionDescription: {
    marginTop: 8,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: '400',
    color: Colors.dark,
  },
  highlight: {
    fontWeight: '700',
  },
  footer: {
    color: Colors.dark,
    fontSize: 12,
    fontWeight: '600',
    padding: 4,
    paddingRight: 12,
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
});

export default App;
```

i started with react-native cli, **https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started (React-Native CLI Quickstart)** trying to run app on simulator with **npx react-native run-ios**
but i can see only blank screen with app name on it..

[image]

..this happened with other basic apps i had created...
what wrong or i am missing...

Comment: Hello can you tell me what is your react-native-cli's version? You can find it with this command: `react-native -v` OR `react-native --version`

Comment: react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.61.4

Comment: its so weird...i am so much confuse...hello world basic app should at least open ..here simple app also not working..

Comment: Actually, It works on my side. Have you checked that is there any error? Also, are you using `react-native init MyApp` command to create a new project right?

Comment: Can you simply clone this project and  in order of: 
`npm i`
`react-native run-ios`

It should work.

Comment: npx react-native init SampleApp i use.... also no error nothing

Comment: My-Mac:SampleBotApp mymac$ react-native run-ios
info Found Xcode workspace "SampleBotApp.xcworkspace"
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace SampleBotApp.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme SampleBotApp -destination id=3F2EAFA6-C11C-443E-9880-F44E9E6EECC8 -derivedDataPath build/SampleBotApp")
......................
info Installing "build/SampleBotApp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SampleBotApp.app"
info Launching "org.reactjs.native.example.SampleBotApp"
success Successfully launched the app on the simulator

Comment: then another window opens then simulator open with white screen and app name on middle as mention above in question

Comment: Have you tried my example?

Comment: react-native init MyApp  , i am creating new app   what is nam i?

Comment: hello, i have created MyApp, but same situation...white screen with MyApp name in middle. similar to above screen...? is it  my app not starting only...there is no error...nothing

Comment: Sir, Have you tried my repo by cloning?

Comment: sorry but i did not find any project link in comment....

Comment: My bad sorry. https://github.com/WrathChaos/react-native-test

Comment: Clone it, `npm i` and `react-native run-ios`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

started working fine for IOS 13... updating Xcode to latest version helps.